# RSACryptoServiceProvider error occurred while decoding OAEP padding

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, rsa

I've read many articles regarding this problem and I cannot seem to find an answer that solves my bug. 
I have a WCF service; my app sends the public RSA key generated and the service returns a set of AES key+IV encrypted with the public key, but when my app then tries to decrypt the keys, I either get "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding" (if I pass true to useOAEP) or "The parameter is incorrect" (if I pass false to useOAEP). For simplicity, this is the entire code used put together, leaving Exception handling aside:

```
public static string EncryptAES(byte[] aesKey, byte[] aesIV, string publicRSAKey)
{
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicRSAKey);
        byte[] encryptedKey = rsa.Encrypt(aesKey, true);
        byte[] encryptedIV = rsa.Encrypt(aesIV, true);
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedKey), "\n", Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedIV));
    }
}
public static byte[] Decrypt(string aesKeyorIV)
{
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
         byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(aesKeyorIV);
         rsa.FromXmlString(RSA_Private_Key);
         return rsa.Decrypt(buffer, true); //Exception thrown here
    }
}
```

(`RSA_Private_Key` is generated in the static constructor using `rsa.ToXmlString(true)`) 
(`publicRSAKey` is passed to the service by sending `rsa.ToXmlString(false)` in the static constuctor) 
I tried using `Encrypt/Decrypt(byte[], false)` but it didn't make any difference. I also tried `Array.Reverse(encryptedKey)` and then `Array.Reverse(buffer)`. 
 
The private key is never sent/modified after it's set so that cannot be it. 
 I'm out of ideas and debugging the WCF service is pretty horrible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88431/discussion-between-zespri-and-cfrozendeath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered where the bug was. My implementation was as follows, simplified:

1. App creates public+private key and sends the public key to the service
2. The service responds with the AES generated keys encrypted with the public key.
3. **The service then tried to decrypt the keys before raising the event to alert the app**.

I changed my implementation such as:

3. The service raised the event with the encrypted message
4. The app decrypts the message with the private key.

Since I'm using one Visual Studio instance to debug the 2 processes (the service's and visual studio debugger's), I didn't realize that the private/public keys were different.

Thanks to @zespri for the testing ideas.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are describing is likely caused by using a different Private Key to Public Key.

If you generate the public and public+private key using the same instance of the RSA provider, then the keys would match. e.g.

```
string publicRSAKey = null;
string publicPlusPrivateRSAKey = null;

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    publicRSAKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
    publicPlusPrivateRSAKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
}
```

If you create the keys from two different instances of the RSA provider, then the public and public+private key's won't match. e.g.

```
string publicRSAKey = null;
string publicPlusPrivateRSAKey = null;

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    publicRSAKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
}

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    publicPlusPrivateRSAKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
}
```

When the keys match, I could round-trip without a problem.  When the keys don't match, I get the "Error occured while decoding OAEP padding.".

Can you verify that the keys match at runtime?

Since the Private Key will contain the Public Key as well, you can look a the contents of each key variable in xml string form, specifically the XML paths of /RSAKeyValue/Modulus and /RSAKeyValue/Exponent, as these should match between the two.

Comment: I wonder if you read almost at the end of my post:
"(RSA_Private_Key is generated in the static constructor using rsa.ToXmlString(true))
(publicRSAKey is passed to the service by sending rsa.ToXmlString(false) in the static constuctor)". I literally meant that RSA_Private_Key and RSA_Public_Key are created on the same RSACryptoServiceProvider instance, one line above the other. The private key does contain the public key, just as it should.